# Why Glance Screen feature will not be available for Lumia 520?

Tags: lumia, lumia-black-update, glance

Nokia is releasing Black update. But they are [saying](http://www.nokia.com/mea-en/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA141614) that Lumia 520 will not receive Glance Screen 2.0 feature due to *hardware restriction*.

Can anyone explain how Glance Screen would work and why Lumia 520 hardware is not compatible?

Answer (score 6):

The Glance screen works without draining the battery too much due to the AMOLED screens. The Nokia Lumia 520/1/5 has a LCD screen, and thus is incompatible.

How it works is the Glance screen turns most of the pixels black. The AMOLED screens have the ability to turn off the pixels when they are black, so they aren't using battery by having the display turned on, unlike LCD screens.

Comment: Can you please cite some references?

Comment: The Lumia 720 supports Glance and has an LCD screen. Same with the Lumia 920.

Comment: This isn't the right answer, the 920 supports glance. I'm guessing the 520 has a different screen controller to the others, meaning that they need extra dev time to support glance on it. I don't think it's technically impossible, just a business decision

Comment: It might be not LCD but `clearBlack` display which is [not present on 520](http://www.gsmarena.com/compare.php3?idPhone1=5322&idPhone2=4967).

Answer (score 2):

I guess there will glance for lumia 520 soon as in the recent "Black" update there is a new extra under "extras + info" as Glance Pinboards App Agent 1.0.1.6. It looks like the hardware is made to match the glance screen and Microsoft is working on making the Glance app available.

[image]

Comment: Actually I think it is because they intend to provide the "double tap to wake" in 520.

Answer (score 2):

As an anecdotal counter-point to all of the other answers here, I own a Lumia 520. It was purchased in the US from AT&T. I am not sure how much or even if the hardware differs much from Lumia 520's elsewhere.

When the device received the Black update, it received the new Glance features as well. I can see all of my app notifications on the Glance screen. Also, the double-tap to wake feature works on my 520, which I have heard others said is missing.

I want to mention, I do not know if this is a hardware or software difference, but it IS possible with some 520's.

Comment: WHAT? I AM SORRY! DID YOU SAY YOU HAVE GLANCE SCREEN IN YOUR 520?

Comment: Yes, it does. Everyone I know locally (in the US buying from ATT), with 520s have Glance and double tap to wake.

Comment: Double tap works everywhere. I'll come back with some links to show that glance screen doesn't work on 520! I am shocked.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Nokia simply built cheaper screens into the Lumia 520 than e.g. into the Lumia 920 (which also has an LCD screen instead of a AMOLED screen,) to get the great price. Thus, it would simply drain your battery... On AMOLED displays the battery drain is the most minimal.