# How to get Glance screen on Lumia 520?

Tags: settings, lumia-520, glance

I have come to know that Glance screen is not available on the Nokia Lumia 520.

Is there some trick to get it working nonetheless? Preferably without compromising battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Please [follow the link](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/3010/why-glance-screen-feature-will-not-be-available-for-lumia-520) to know why?

> The Glance screen works without draining the battery too much due to the AMOLED screens. The Nokia Lumia 520/1/5 has a LCD screen, and thus is incompatible.
>
> How it works is the Glance screen turns most of the pixels black. The AMOLED screens have the ability to turn off the pixels when they are black, so they aren't using battery by having the display turned on, unlike LCD screens.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments of the answer you quote, this is incorrect - phones with LCD displays like the 720 and 920 do support Glance.

Comment: True! I guess the feature called 'clear black' is explained here and the reason for which Glance is supported in LCD displays as well. Although 'Clear black' feature is not supported in Lumia 520/1/5. So, I guess...

Comment: Nope, ClearBlack is something completely different. It's a set of polarising filters that help reduce screen reflections. See here for more information: http://conversations.nokia.com/2010/11/04/so-what-is-clearblack-display